# Duplicate questions that raise better answers?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, exact-duplicates

Often I see duplicate questions that have great answers.

- Can the original question be edited to reflect all the duplicates titles in the body as a foot note?
- Can answers be migrated from the duplicate if requested?
- Can the OP delete and post their answer from the duplicate to the first original question?
- Can duplicate answers be posted to the original question?
- What other ways can good answers to duplicate questions be reflected in the original not duplicate question?

[Why can't airline pilots listen to music while flying?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/58551/why-cant-airline-pilots-listen-to-music-while-flying)